# Adding a help popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add "help" information about some of the items on my web application. User will take cursor to that item and help will show up in popup box or a small window. Does anyone have a good example to show in jquery or javascript?

Comment: It's called a tooltip, and a Google search will give you a gazillion examples.

Comment: **What have you tried?**

Comment: @adeneo - Thanks ..damn I forgot what it used to be called. I think that should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite open but you could have an initially hidden DIV whose content and position would be dynamic:

```
<div id="tooltip" style="display:none; position: absolute; z-index: 1000"></div>
```

The z-index property is to ensure the visibility of the DIV. Of course, the value depends on  whether you have other elements with higher z-index or not.

Then you could create a couple of JS functions: one for showing the div and another for hidding it:

```
function showTooltip (content, x, y) {
    $('#tooltip')
        .html(content)
        .css({left: x, top: y})
        .show();
}
function hideTooltip()
{
    $('#tooltip').hide();
}
```

The functions would be triggered by mouse events, for example (mousenter, mouseleave, ...).
Of course the aesthetic of the DIV could be tuned through CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of JQuery tooltip plugins:

- [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)
- [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/)
- [TipTip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin)
- [PowerTip](http://stevenbenner.github.com/jquery-powertip/)
- [clueTip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/)

Answer (score 0):

This is also a nice plugin to create tours for new users

[jquery-joyride](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin)